# How to bind "Power Save Mode" toggling to a keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am somewhat annoyed by the need to use the main menu every time I wish to turn "Power Save Mode" on or off. Can use a hot key for this? I use IntelliJ Idea 11.1.2 Community Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>CTRL ALT S</kbd> to go to settings
- Search for **Keymap** in the left hand side.
- Make a copy of the key map by clicking on the **Copy** give it a name
- Search for **Power** on the right hand side to get Power Save
- Click on **Power Save Mode**
- Assign the key binding in the dialog box presented.

Checked this in the Community Edition.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+Shift+A (Help | Find action), type "power", see "Power save mode", Enter.